# Dynamic Jquery Menu from Database, PHP to JSP

Tags: jquery, database, jsp, dynamic, menu

I need is a menu that is dynamically generated. I watched this example PHP code and MySQL database using here:

View: http://dynamicjqueryme.sourceforge.net

Full code: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicjqueryme

I'm trying to implement it in Netbeans IDE v7.3, JDK 7u45, MySQL Community Server v5.6.13 and GlassFish 4.0 Open Source Edition.

Can you show some example like or similar dynamic menu but in JSP?

I just need to generate tags ul and li with database and a logical order similar to the example.

Comment: hi mee to need this....presently we are populating menus using map..if you know above way in jsp reply here.